# How to render images using dompdf?

Tags: php, image, dompdf

Following is the code which I used to generate pdf file.

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
$html =
    '<html><body>'.
    'Generating pdf test'.
    '<img src="http://mysite/logo.jpg"/>'.
    '<img src="logo.jpg"/>'.
    '</body></html>';

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();

    file_put_contents("Test.pdf" , $dompdf->output());
?>
```

I have also set DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE to true. Still both the images are not rendering. It renders broken image as red cross mark, but the text is rendering fine. I'm using dompdf-0.5.2 and the server is godaddy.

Am I doing anything wrong or I have to additionally configure anything?

Comment: perhaps src of img is incorrect

Comment: @ashkufaraz: I have double checked it. It is in correct path.

Comment: Do you have read/write access to the directory specified by DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR?

Comment: Also, you should consider upgrading to [dompdf 0.6.1](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.6.1) as it has many improvements.

Comment: ok. Let me try with 0.6.1